# git-upload-pack not permitted using JGIT

Tags: gitlab, jgit

My intent here is to use a "Personal Access Token" to be able to clone/pull from this repo (GitLab) in a java application. I just can't figure out how to get around this error.

Here is the code I have.

```
    String accessToken = conf.getString("accessToken");

    String uri = "https://gitlab-ci-token:" + accessToken + "@gitlab.com/dfurrer/cosmotronsBinaries.git";

    CredentialsProvider cp = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("PRIVATE-TOKEN", accessToken);
    git = Git.cloneRepository()
                    .setURI(uri)
                    .setCredentialsProvider(cp)
                    .setRemote("origin")
                    .setBranch("master")
                    .call();
```

I get his exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab-ci-token@gitlab.com/dfurrer/cosmotronsBinaries.git: git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://gitlab-ci-token@gitlab.com/dfurrer/cosmotronsBinaries.git/'
```

Comment: Have you tried what I summarized here http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/ ?

Comment: Yes, that was the example that I worked from. I had it working using username/password but now using "Personal Access Token" I get his message.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue. I was creating a personal access key with read_user and read_registry only. Once I created a token with api permissions I'm able to clone.

Comment: Please can you share more info here in the answer? You were creating a personal access key in Git portal or where else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Jgit`: use `UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider` to authenticate with token, the username parameter may be `token` or use the owner name from repository url or be empty, the password parameter's value is your token value, the three style all work well in my way:

```
new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("token","Personal Access Token")); 

new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("the owner name of the repository","Personal Access Token")); 

new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("","Personal Access Token"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Git config, try change to "JDK built-in" for HTTP client

refer: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1104150/

Comment: Is that what we can do from STS or Eclipse? If yes, can you please tell how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem, I just solved it right now... At the point where you create a personal token, you have to give it permission to read and write. However, when i did mine, i grant all the permission read and write for testing cause i don't know which one to give permission to.
If you want to create personal access token, it should be the beta version not the classic. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).