# Config server with private git repository

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

I want to use private git repository with my config server. Here is my `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 100
spring:
  application:
    name: smth-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/smth/smth
          default-label: main
          username: smth
          password: smth
          host-key-algorithm: ssh-rsa
          ignore-local-ssh-settings: true
          host-key: ssh-rsa smth== github.com
          private-key: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
            smth
            -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/smth/smth: not authorized
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:544)
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Since you're using HTTPS as the protocol, providing a private key is not going to work. Either change the clone URL to be a SSH compatible one or use an access token instead of the `private-key`.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Thank you! You were right, I also added few more configs and got it work =)

Comment: Can you share the solution for the issue? @majorMobilych

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430335/git-upload-pack-not-permitted-using-jgit/77570264#77570264

Answer (score 3):

For this to work with a private repository you must use a git access token (which you can generate following this [steps](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)) on your password property.

so for example

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: yourgithubrepo 
          username: ${GIT_USER}
          password: pasteyouraccesstoken
          default-label: "main"
```

that should work

Answer (score 1):

In your config server application properties:

```
 profiles:
    active: git
    
  spring:
    cloud:
      config:
        server:
          git:
            uri: https://github.com/${GIT_USER}/${GIT_REPO}.git
            username: ${GIT_USER}
            password: pasteyouraccesstoken
            clone-on-start: true
            default-label: ${GIT_BRANCH}
            searchPaths: ${FOLDER_PATH}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).